# Is 'carry' a daily usage or it's an internet word?

Tags: word-usage

In online video games, the strongest player in a group is called the carry. Is it a daily usage? Like in school projects or office team works? If not how is it usually described?

Comment: I would assume that this is a coined usage of the verb, which has several definitions in this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen nor heard it in this sense in the West Coast USA, but I can imagine being used as a coined usage of the verb in the contexts you mention, chiefly in this sense:

> **[carry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carry)**
>
> 15 : to be chiefly or solely responsible for the success, effectiveness, or continuation of
>
> > a player capable of carrying a team
> >
> > Her performance carried the play.

Answer (score 3):

I am 41 years of age and have never heard that term used in everyday speech.  Commonly one would say "I felt as though I carried the rest of the team" or "It was Lillian who was carrying the rest of the group" -meaning they did all the work while the others slackened off.
I checked with my 18 year old daughter, who is pretty up-to-date with trending colloquial terms and she has advised me that it is also not used by people of her generation (although she WAS familiar with the gaming term)
Hope this helps!  :-)

Comment: hmm, interesting, I've heard the term mostly in MOBA games, but I can't tell the country of origin of those players.